# How to install DisplayLink driver on LinuxMint 17.3

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, usb, display, displaylink

I have a USB 3.0 docking station connected with my laptop having LinuxMint 17.3. I can't manage to install DisplayLink driver on it. I could make it work with Ubuntu 15.04, but with LinuxMint it wan't recognize external monitor, even though there is no error message during the install procedure.

I tried to follow some proposal on [DisplayLink forum](http://support.displaylink.com/forums/287786-displaylink-feature-suggestions/suggestions/7988955-support-linux-on-all-your-devices?page=1&per_page=20), and I tried to modify installation file so SYSTEMINITDAEMON had systemd or upstart values, but none of these worked.

Since I already found some posts reported it worked for LinuxMint 17.2, I guess it's possible, but I couldn't find exact instructions if something else should be changed in installation script.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an nVidia card install the driver for it
Then open the nVidia application an select a profile to use "Intel (PowerSaver Mode)" 
That should bring up your monitors right away